How to import a module that is in the same file?
Here is the contents of my code file "test.exs":
defmodule Test do
  def f(:a, x) do x + 1 end
  def f(:b, x) do x - 1 end
end

import Test
IO.puts f :a, 3
IO.puts f :b, 3

Running of this file in shell by elixir test.exs fails. I think the problem comes from import Test. So what is the right way to import a moudule which is defined in the same file?

Move the end to the last line. The delete the import Test line.

Thank you, GavinBrelstaff. Following your instructions, I get error: undefined function f/2 (there is no such import). Why?

You could do it like this:
defmodule Test do
  def f(:a, x) do x + 1 end
  def f(:b, x) do x - 1 end
end

defmodule MyScript do
  import Test

  def run do
    IO.puts f :a, 3
    IO.puts f :b, 3
  end
end

MyScript.run()

So you can call it "in the same file".
However, it has to be done within another module.
I don't know why it's like this. I bet there is a really good reason though.

As for the why, my understanding is that import happens when expanding the code, before any module in the file actually gets compiled.
When trying to import, the module code can't be found and is marked as scheduled here.

I don't believe this is possible: import is a compile-time convenience -- it's basically doing copy/paste at compile time, so AFAIK it requires the source module to be compiled.  If you're trying to import the module from inside the same file where it is defined, the module isn't compiled yet, so it's not available for importing.  The error I see when I try this says:
error: module Test is not loaded but was defined. This happens when you depend on a module in the same context in which it is defined.

which seems to suggest that this is not possible for the reasons mentioned.

So, the only way to test the funciton f has to be Test.f? No other way to invoke the funciton name directily?

Not if you're trying to call it from the same file.

But modules defined in the file .iex.exs can be import in it(.iex.exs). I'm confused.

I found this thread about .iex.exs, thought it might be relevant and provide some pointers.
